# different units and design of datastructure

Tags: python, data-structures, units-of-measurement

I am trying to write a program that calculates nutrition level in food.Suppose I have this data(may be incorrect)

```
10 grams of bread has 68 mg sodium.
1 medium slice is 50 grams.

1 cup of milk has 98 mg sodium
1 cup of milk is 236 ml(or 244 grams)
which means 10 grams of milk has 0.004 grams of Sodium
```

The user may enter number of slices or grams of bread he ate or if it is milk -how many cups or how many ml of milk he drank

So,how should I design the data structure? should I keep a single unit measure internally like grams and convert slice,ml,cup etc into that?

```
    food details ={ 
     'whitebread':{'unit':10,'slice':50,'sodium':0.068},
     'milk':{'unit':10,'cup':244,'sodium':0.004},...
     }
```

Comment: what calculations do you want to perform? Do you want to convert between mg, g etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, you should convert internally to a single measurement unit and convert at input and at output.

It is even more important in python than in other as it is [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_typing#Dynamic_typing) - you cannot explicitly declare what type do a function use or return. Consider an example:

```
def get_sodium_for_bread(quantity_of_bread):
    ...
    return quantity_of_sodium
```

You cannot explicitly define type of `quantity_...` variable like in C (`miligrams_t get_sodium(slices_t bread)`). If you use different units you will get lost very quickly.

It would be the simpliest if you used a single unit for everything if possible, e.g. grams

```
food_props_per_gram = {
    'bread': {'sodum': 0.000012},
    'milk': {'sodium': 0.00032}
}

units_to_grams = {
    'slice': 100.0,
    'cup': '250.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple representation are [named tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). They are okay as long as you do not need an full-blown object-oriented design.

```
from collections import namedtuple

details = namedtuple('details', 'name sodium amount unit')
food = namedtuple('food', 'details amount unit')
unit = namedtuple('unit', 'name weight')

gram = unit('gram', 1)
slice = unit('slice', 50)
cup = unit('cup', 244)

bread = details(name='bread', sodium=68,  amount=10, unit=gram)
f_bread = food(details=bread, amount=1, unit=slice)

milk = details(name='milk', sodium=98, amount=1, unit=cup)
f_milk = food(details=milk, amount=10, unit=gram)


for f in (f_bread, f_milk):
    total = 1.0 / 1000 * f.amount * f.unit.weight * f.details.sodium / f.details.amount / f.details.unit.weight
    print(
        "%d %s of %s has %0.3f grams sodium" % 
        (f.amount, f.unit.name, f.details.name, total))
```

Output:

```
1 slice of bread has 0.340 grams sodium
10 gram of milk has 0.004 grams sodium
```

I slit up the food details and units from the actual food intake. A kind of bread is probably eaten more than once.